# synchronizing a statement object to avoid duplicate a string in database table by concurrent clients

Tags: sql, oracle, servlets

I have the following piece of code for reading a value from a table and then increment it then enter the incremented value in the table.This code is for a LAN-project and is in a servlet. So when concurrent clients accesses this servlet then they would read the value at the same time and thus increment the value at the same time too and then enter the value in the table, then there will be multiple rows of the same value which i don't want. I can avoid it by assigning unique attribute to the variable in the table itself but then a separate process would run in the database. So, I want to avoid this situation from the client side itself and so I am thinking of synchronizing the statement object. I am looking for suggestions on the issue.

```
System.out.println("1");
Db mydata=(Db)getServletContext().getAttribute("Database");
conn=mydata.getCon();
System.out.println("2");
stmn=conn.createStatement();
System.out.println("3");

    synchronised(stmn)
    {           

rst=stmn.executeQuery("select max(pregno) from regt");

while(rst.next())
{

    rg=rst.getString(1);


}
reg=Integer.parseInt(rg);
reg++;
System.out.print(reg);
stmn.execute("insert into regt values('"+reg+"')");
    }
```

Comment: Why not use a sequence and let oracle handle this?

Comment: I agree with @Robert. Don't re-invent the wheel. Most problems have already been solved. Use the tools provided.

Comment: Also, why are you retrieving the value as a string and converting it, rather than using `getInt()`? And why aren't you using a prepared statement and bind variable for the insert? Both are moot if you use a sequence of course, but still...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Robert, @Turophile and @Alex Poole said, the proper way to handle this would be a sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE pregno NOCACHE START WITH 1;
```

Your Java code would simply select from the sequence to get higher numbers:

```
SELECT pregno.nextval FROM DUAL;
```

If that is not an option for some reasons, at least change the code from `SELECT MAX(regno)` and `INSERT` to a `SELECT regno FOR UPDATE` and `UPDATE regno` pair...